# Why the disjunctive ASP program cannot return both disjunct predicates instance in an answer?

Tags: logic-programming, answer-set-programming, clingo

I am a newbie to ASP ([Answer Set Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Answer_set_programming)).

I tried the following program in clingo [online version](https://potassco.org/clingo/run/) (reasoning mode = enumerate all)

```
% instance
member(dave).

% encoding
edu(X);rich(X) :- member(X).
```

It returns:

```
Answer: 1
member(dave) rich(dave)
Answer: 2
member(dave) edu(dave)
SATISFIABLE
```

But why there is no "Answer: 3" ? Something like:

```
Answer: 3
member(dave) edu(dave) rich(dave)
```

This answer also satisfies the rule `edu(X);rich(X) :- member(X).`.

From the perspective of logic,

`edu(X);rich(X) :- member(X).`

means

`member(X) -> edu(X) ∨ rich(X)`

So there ought to be another answer that both `edu(X)` and rich(X) are true.

BTW, if I add the two facts about charlie manually:

```
% instance
member(charlie).
rich(charlie).
edu(charlie).

% encoding
edu(X);rich(X) :- member(X).
```

Then it returns the correct answer as expected:

```
Answer: 1
member(charlie) edu(charlie) rich(charlie)
SATISFIABLE
```

Very thanks!

---

Some background information:

I have this question, because I am comparing traditional Logic Programming (e.g Prolog) vs Answer Set Programming (e.g. clingo), although they use different theoretical framework.

The disjunctive programs of the form in clingo:

```
a_1 ∨ a_2 ... ∨ a_n <- body
```

can not be represented in Prolog out of box.

A related question, see [Using And clause in HEAD of a prolog statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822039/using-and-clause-in-head-of-a-prolog-statement)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we can use the form Choice Rule to represent the logical disjunctive semantics in clingo.

Example 1:

```
% instance
member(dave).

% encoding
1 {edu(X);rich(X)} :- member(X).
```

returns

```
Answer: 1
member(dave) edu(dave)
Answer: 2
member(dave) rich(dave)
Answer: 3
member(dave) rich(dave) edu(dave)
SATISFIABLE
```

Example 2:

```
% instance
member(dave).
member(charlie).
rich(charlie).
edu(charlie).

% encoding
1 {edu(X);rich(X)} :- member(X).
```

returns

```
Answer: 1
edu(charlie) rich(charlie) member(dave) member(charlie) edu(dave)
Answer: 2
edu(charlie) rich(charlie) member(dave) member(charlie) rich(dave)
Answer: 3
edu(charlie) rich(charlie) member(dave) member(charlie) rich(dave) edu(dave)
SATISFIABLE
```

It works as expected, although I have no idea whether is it correct semantically.